# Play A Random Sound onTouch

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I'm trying to play a random sound onTouch event (currently working), but the sound is actually played twice onTouch event instead of once as intended.  I'm assuming this is due to the UP and Down onTouch event.  Any thoughts?

NOTE: I commented out the additional random sound files while testing.

```
package com.tmapps.wiub;

import java.util.Random;
import com.tmapps.wiub.SoundManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Soundboard extends Activity {
    private SoundManager mSoundManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // FULLSCREEN CODE
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
        mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
        mSoundManager.addSound(0, R.raw.sound0);

     // COMMENTED OUT WHILE TESTING  
     // mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.sound1);
     // mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.sound2);
     // mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.sound3);
     // mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.sound4);
     // mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.sound5);
     // mSoundManager.addSound(6, R.raw.sound6);
     // mSoundManager.addSound(7, R.raw.sound7);
     // mSoundManager.addSound(8, R.raw.sound8);
     // mSoundManager.addSound(9, R.raw.sound9);

    };

        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.nextInt(1);

        switch (evt.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mSoundManager.playSound(x);
            return super.onTouchEvent(evt);

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because both ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP are firing, implement on code only on one of them

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) 
    {
        switch (evt.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help kishu27.  I updated the onTouch code as you suggested and everything is working correctly now.

Comment: By chance do you have any thoughts on how I might gradually increase the volume over X seconds using AudioManager?

Comment: I don't think that is doable, I'm sorry I didn't have any idea about that. But it is against android app design fundamentals. Even if you can, and you should never modify system settings. User may not like it, besides APIs may change prohibiting your app to do that and create problems with your app. But I suggest you post a new question. People in stackoverflow answer for reputation points, so no one will reply here