# Android - Playing random sound from OnTouch with SoundManager

Tags: android, random, ontouchlistener

I am wanting a random sound to play whenever the user touches the screen.  I have found and used these other posts to help set up my project and get me moving in the right direction.

[Play random sound file on button press - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885420/play-random-sound-file-on-button-press-android)

[Issue With Sound Manager Playing Random Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168826/issue-with-sound-manager-playing-random-files)

[Issue With Sound Manager Playing Random Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168826/issue-with-sound-manager-playing-random-files)

[Play A Random Sound onTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115238/play-a-random-sound-ontouch)

The problem is that with my current code I am getting a NullPointerException.  The LogCat is showing it coming from two spots:

In the Main class at

```
int x = r.nextInt(1);
```

and in the SoundManager class at

```
mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
```

I know this is just something I am overlooking, but can't seem to figure it out.  Pretty new to Android and Java developing so that is why.  I have included both the Main and SoundManager classes.  Any help would be appreciated!

MAIN CLASS

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int x = r.nextInt(1);

    private SoundManager mSoundManager;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mIll);
        image.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
        mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
        mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.m1);
        mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.m2);
        mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.m3);
        mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.m4);
        mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.m5);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) 
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            mSoundManager.playSound(x);
        }

        break;

    }

    return true;

    }

}
```

SOUND MANAGER

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class SoundManager {

    private SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private Context mContext;
    public static final int maxSounds = 1;

    public SoundManager() {

    }

    public void initSounds(Context theContext) {
        mContext = theContext;
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addSound(int Index, int SoundID) {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));

    }

    public void playSound(int index) {

        int streamVolume = mAudioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume,
                1, 0, 1f);
    }

}
```

Comment: index this value is null try to print that

Comment: post your logcat (to verify where exactly you're having the second error. I'm pretty sure my answer rectifies the first one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is

```
int x = r.nextInt(1);  //<<<<
```

this line always Generate 0 as random number  and `0` key is not exist in `HashMap` .check null before getting value from `HashMap` as :

```
if(mSoundPoolMap.containsKey(index)){
 mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume,
                1, 0, 1f);
}
else{
 // Generate  next number

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makes some sense to me.  In the else statement am I generating the next number with another Random call?  Or how does that work.  Still a bit confused on that part.

Comment: @BradMc : in else block if index not exist in `mSoundPoolMap` then generate another number because u have 5 items in `mSoundPoolMap` then use 5 from generating random number instead of 1

Comment: @BradMc : use ` Random r = new Random();
 int randomInt=0;
     for (int idx = 0; idx <= 5; ++idx){
      int randomInt = r.nextInt(2);
      if(randomInt !=0)
           break;
     }` for generating random number

Comment: Thanks for the code sample.  That helped me visualize it more.  Once I implemented your suggestions though nothing happened.  I'm no longer getting the NullPointerException, but there are also no sounds being played.

Comment: @BradMc : i just give u logic and where is issue in current code . if u are getting any issue then just debug your code using logs and check which value is passed in this `mSoundManager.playSound(x);` line

Comment: @BradMc : one more  suggestion use `mSoundManager.initSounds(Main.this);` instead of `mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());`

Answer (score 0):

Move your initialization to the onCreate() section

```
  Random r ;
  int x ;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    r= new Random();
    x= r.nextInt(1);
    ...
}
```